# rspec NoMethodError 'has_content?' 'has_title?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Im pretty new to ruby on rails.
I just finished this tutorial and i am trying to make my own ruby website from scratch
As soon as i switched my sin-tax to the less verbose one i am getting errors:

the errors I get are:

```
 1) Pages Home page
Failure/Error: it { should have_content('Home') }
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `has_content?' for "Home page":String
# ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) Pages Home page
    Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Home') }
    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `has_title?' for "Home page":String
    # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

this is my rspec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('Home') }
    it { should have_title('Home') }    
  end

end
```

I have no idea what is going on did i forget to include something in my gemfile? 
If you want any more info comment and ill include it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
it 'has home title' do
  expect(page).to have_title('Home')
end

it 'has home content' do
  expect(page).to have_content('Home')
end
```

Or

```
subject { page }

it { should have_title('Home') }
it { should have_content('Home') }
```

Comment: yea thats what i mean changing the syntax from the more verbose one. This syntax works but it gets pretty cluttered later on so i just wanted to use the shorter syntax. Thanks for the suggestion thou

Comment: @Xitcod13 I edited my answer, try it with `subject` hope it will work